# Kerr frequency combs in ring resonators

Tags: optics, frequency, fiber-optics, laser-cavity

Is it possible to generate Kerr frequency combs using a macroscopic fiber ring resonator? Or is the phenomenon exclusive to monolithic microresonators?

If this is possible, would the presence of additional spatial modes (i.e., higher powers) be an advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to generate Kerr frequency combs using a macroscopic fiber ring resonator?

There's nothing stopping you from doing this. Frequency combs come from bulk optics, and the switch to microresonators is a rather recent development.

(On the other hand, if you want to have a macroscopic fiber *ring*, then you should think very carefully about how you're coupling light into and out of the resonator. Evanescent coupling works well for microscopic fibers, but it's unlikely to scale well to higher fiber diameters.)

> If this is possible, would the presence of additional spatial modes (i.e., higher powers) be an advantage?

This is unlikely, unless you really don't care about the coherence (in which case - why are you working on a frequency comb?). The cavity resonance represents a single transverse mode, and whether this is a single eigenmode of the fiber or not is ultimately irrelevant.

As to engineering advantages, this depends completely on the particulars of the system, what tradeoffs you've done elsewhere, and what your design priorities are. It's entirely possible that there are systems where it can be beneficial to use macroscopic fibers. You'd have to ask an optical engineer what those are.

Comment: For a macroscopic fiber ring, can you not simply use a coupler to transfer light in and out of the resonator? In fact, the simplest macroscopic ring would probably be made by taking one output of a coupler and feeding it back to one of its input ports (that gives a cavity length of 1-2 meters).